# second Datetimepicker choose only date chosen by first datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

```
<div class="col-md-5 no-padding">
    <div class="input-group date form_datetime_from col-md-12" id="leavefromdate" data-date="2015-01-01 05:25" data-link-field="leavefrom">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" readonly>  <span class="input-group-addon success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="leavefrom" name="ApplyLeave[leavefrom]" value="" />
    <br/>
</div>  <span class="col-md-2 no-padding" style="float:left;line-height:35px;text-align:center">To</span>

<div class="col-md-5 no-padding">
    <div class="input-group date form_datetime_to col-md-12" id="leavetodate" data-date="" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd H:i" data-link-field="leaveto">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" readonly>  <span class="input-group-addon success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="leaveto" name="ApplyLeave[leaveto]" value="" />
    <br/>
</div>
```

im using this datetimepicker http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php

my jquery code id

```
$(".form_datetime_from").datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii',
    autoclose: true,
    //linkField: "leaveto",
}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    $("#leaveto").val($("#leavefrom").val());
    $("#leavetodate").attr('data-date', $("#leavefrom").val());
});
```

//date picker 2

```
$(".form_datetime_to").datetimepicker({
    //setStartDate: '2012-01-01',
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii',
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: "leavefrom",
});
```

I want to set the min date for the second datetimepicker is the first datetimepicker value.
also user can select the date only in the first datetimepicker , not able to choose before and after dates

Answer (score 1):

To select only date you have to set minview to 2

```
$('.form_datetime_from').datetimepicker({
                 format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                 autoclose: true,
                 minView: 2,

           });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
 $( ".form_datetime_from" ).datetimepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 3,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( ".form_datetime_to" ).datetimepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
}
});
$( ".form_datetime_to" ).datetimepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 3,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( ".form_datetime_from" ).datetimepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
}
});
```

Basically when first date picker close, you have to set min date for second date picker at that time.

See another [jquery example](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range).